# How to render Web Api to a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I wrote some code in webapi ValueConroller. When I try to execute it I'm getting JSON data which is by default saving to text file (IE 8.0), XML output when tried with Mozilla Firefox .

I am not sure how to display my `List<country>` which will be having list of countries and i am writing this method in value controller like

```
public IEnumarable<countrylist> getcounrty()
{
obj.method1().tolist(); // method1 will return list<country> where country is a class in my BLL
}
```

I want the method output to be bonded with Dropdownlist . Becoz there is no VIEW is webapi I am confused how to do it

Any ideas are appreciated.

EDIT : konckout.js is a alternative ? my colleagues ad-viced me so any best alternative mates

Comment: Welcome...show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, can you try to add more information?

Comment: Is the browser asking you to open a file? Could you please show how you are returning the ActionResult from your controller method.

Comment: Big Daddy : well i tried little and i am confused with binding my output to display to end user ? Thinking using what ?
Jeroen Vannevel :edited once plz check and let me know
lrb: nope but when i tried with IE 8.0 initially asking to save later when i open a file its in JASON format but Mozilla directly displaying in XML format . BUT i need list in dropdownlist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web API and MVC have **different purposes**.

The purpose of ASP.NET **Web API** is to build HTTP-based **web services** (also sometimes called REST services). Out of the box, it only supports

- JSON
- XML

although you can implement other formatters yourself, if you need to exchange data in another format. In theory, you could write a custom formatter to produce HTML, but there's no reason to do that.

If you need to produce HTML, then use ASP.NET **MVC**.

Comment: nice explanation . any ideas on knockout.js linked to webapi output ?

Comment: That would probably work well; personally, I use AngularJS to build a SPA that consumes the HTTP API.

Comment: well apart from your explanation can you possibly show some links to understand WEBAPI consumption and dealing that webapi to anjular or knockout.js . Thank you

Comment: "Well actually" it supports `text/plain` and `application/octet-stream` out of the box too.  :-)

Comment: @supercool I have an AngularJS sample code base here: https://github.com/ploeh/booking-web-ui It consumes an ASP.NET Web API.